# findViewById for dynamically added View

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, addition, dynamically-generated

Is it possible to find the added TextView to update it with other options.
I am adding by this code new TextView with a Button. Now, I want also set a onClickListerner for the dynamically added TextViews. For this I have to find them with findViewById method. But they aren't createt yet.

Can I make this in a other way and if yes, How?

```
    Button hinzufügenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hinzufügen_Button);

    hinzufügenButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick (View view){
            EditText tischName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tisch_name_EditText);
            TextView tisch = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tisch.setText(tischName.getText());
            tisch.setAllCaps(true);
            tisch.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tisch.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9FA8DA"));
            tisch.setTextSize(25);
            tisch.setId(id);
            id++;


            LinearLayout tischeAnzeigen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tische_LinearLayout);

            tischeAnzeigen.addView(tisch);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why? you already have a reference when you add them,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `onClickListener` as you create your dynamic views

Example:

```
...
tisch.setId(id);
tisch.setOnClickListener(yourListener);
...
```

Comment: Oh yeah sry i am pretty new in android and java

Answer (score 0):

You can use setId to add an id.  But you probably don't need to.  If you're creating a view dynamically, you have a reference to it when you create it.  Just set it on that reference.  No need to find it.